# how to take a screenshot in selenium and paste as a HTML page?

Tags: python, selenium, tableau-api

I am aware we can take screenshots using Selenium. But is it possible to save the screenshot as a HTML page? can anyone please help?

Comment: What do you mean by "saving a screenshot"?  Do you want to create a HTML page containing the image?  Or do you want to get and save the HTML of the page you're looking at with Selenium?

Comment: I wished to save the image as a .htm if at all it was possible

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Selenium and I'm not sure if you want an automated flow or a one-shot solution.

If it helps in your case, or is a helpful workaround,  remember that in Windows you can always manually take a screenshot (  fn + Windows + prt sc on my laptop ) which saves a .png image to your pictures/screenshots directory and then manually or via a script display that picture on a web page.   Or ( windows + shift + s) to manually take a screen shot of a smaller part of what's showing on your screen.

Or ALT + PRSCR to snapshot the active window.
https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/how-to-take-screenshots-on-laptop-quickly-easily/

Or you can use any software that can simulate key-clicks.
Here's a Python solution if you can run Python from Selenium.

https://datatofish.com/screenshot-python/